# Can someone help to know how to extract structure information from DW_TAG_structure_type from .debug_info file?

Tags: c++, c, elf, dwarf

I am beginner to dwarf library and I know there are tools like GDB to extract structure information from elf file (with ptype command). I am interested to know how do we decode/extract the **DW_TAG_structure_type** manually from dwarf **.debug_info** file?

Basically I am trying to write a dwarf library for parsing structure from an elf file and trying to understand how we can iterate through **DW_TAG_structure_type**. For example, below is the DIE for **DW_TAG_structure_type timer_stamp**. Now how do we now what should be the first member of this structure as here it is followed by a union rather than a member. Any reference or document which explains how to completely decode a structure will be very helpful.

```
<1><f63181>: Abbrev Number: 82 (DW_TAG_structure_type)
    <f63182>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x19ae36): timer_stamp 
    <f63186>   DW_AT_byte_size   : 256  
    <f63188>   Unknown AT value: 88: 16 
    <f63189>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 86   
    <f6318a>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 50   
    <f6318b>   DW_AT_decl_column : 1    
    <f6318c>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0xf6335f>   
 <2><f63190>: Abbrev Number: 18 (DW_TAG_union_type)
    <f63191>   DW_AT_byte_size   : 8    
    <f63192>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 86   
    <f63193>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 50   
    <f63194>   DW_AT_decl_column : 1    
    <f63195>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0xf631b2>   
 <3><f63199>: Abbrev Number: 19 (DW_TAG_member)
    <f6319a>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x229609): status  
    <f6319e>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 86   
    <f6319f>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 50   
    <f631a0>   DW_AT_decl_column : 1    
    <f631a1>   DW_AT_type        : <0xf5fa6d>   
 <3><f631a5>: Abbrev Number: 19 (DW_TAG_member)
    <f631a6>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x21f601): mgr_relay   
    <f631aa>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 86   
    <f631ab>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 50   
    <f631ac>   DW_AT_decl_column : 1    
    <f631ad>   DW_AT_type        : <0xf5fa6d>
```

Comment: That will involve plenty of DWARF reference chasing. Every member DIE has a type attribyte, which is a ref to a datatype DIE, and the type might be a composite one, too, etc. To get a better idea what are you up against, try visualizing the DWARF tree with DWARF Explorer: https://github.com/sevaa/dwex Disclaimer: I wrote that.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to write a dwarf library for parsing structure from elf file

1. This is a non-trivial undertaking and
2. Is reinventing the wheel -- [libdwarf](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libdwarf/) already exists.

> Any reference or document which explains how to completely decode a structure will be very helpful.

You'll want to read the DWARF [standard](http://dwarfstd.org/Dwarf5Std.php).

Comment: My main intention is to extract the the information from dw_tag_structure_type or to decode the structure. I am able to parse the dwarf to get the .debug_info section. Now the next step is to decode any structure just looking for that.